# Sybase ASE system stored procedures are returning nothing

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

System stored procedures such as `sp_displayroles`, `sp_helpdevice`, amongst many others, are returning nothing. When I run `sp_helpdevice;`, all I get as a return value is a string 'sp_helpdevice'. Any idea how to check what's wrong?

I would like to see what devices are present so I may run `ALTER DATABASE <database> LOG ON <device>= '20m';` to allow for larger transaction logs.

Edit:
I have the proper permission with sa_role.

Comment: Do you have the necessary permissions to execute the system stored procedures?

Comment: Yes, I did. Sorry, this has been resolved, turns out I should be using ISQL to interact with the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the problem. I was running the queries via Oracle SQL Developer. It was giving problems probably due to the SQL developer's Sybase DB driver not being very compatible with ASE v16. After using the native ISQL, I can see the results formatted properly.